# Getting 500 error after deploying my laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I'm getting 500 erro after deploying my web app, I get the following error:

```
#1 /var/www/gabrielgb.es/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(122): file_put_contents('/var/www/gabrie...', '<?php $__env->s...', 0)
#2 /var/www/gabrielgb.es/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(122): Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem->put('/var/www/gabrie...', '<?php $__env->s...')
#3 /var/www/gabrielgb.es/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(51): Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler->compile('/var/www/gabrie...')
#4 /var/www/gabrielgb.es/vendor/larave...
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/gabrielgb.es/storage/framework/views/19e7e3b2e87a6fea9c23327a9ff41e59e6f424c9.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/gabrielgb.es/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/gabrie...', 122, Array)
#1 /var/www/gabrielgb.es/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(122): file_put_contents('/var/www/gabrie...', '<?php $__env->s...', 0)
#2 /var/www/gabrielgb.es/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(122): Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem->put('/var/www/gabrie...', '<?php $__env->s...')
#3 /var/www/gabrielgb.es/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(51): Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler->co
```

afaik this is a permissions issue but I don't get why I'm getting this since I gave 775 permissions to bootstrap and sorage folders as you can see here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z869h.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/au6vt.png

I'm using a digitalocean VPS and nginx as web server.
What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Did you give those 775 permissions to *everything inside those folders* as well?

Comment: Check the owner of that folder.

Comment: @TahaPaksu https://i.imgur.com/QKVcDQV.png this are the permissions f the folder

Comment: Nope, not root, all the storage folder and below.

Comment: Yes, they all have 775 permissions, I used chmod -R

Comment: give 775 permission to vendor folder then try